# Pine script rsi upper and lower band color fill

Tags: pine-script

i marge 2 rsi into 1 but when rsi cross the upper or lower band then i want to fill it in some color.
i tried to use like this fill(upline, dnline, color=coloraqua, transp=80, title="Fill background between Up line and Down line")  but its not working.
here is what want in this pic, but not remove 2 rsi line.
https://i.gyazo.com/98bab6d0c2b9a9d6cd2f2d5cbe7f668e.png

here is the code

```
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI1", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"


plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)
rsiUpperBand = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")
```

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://www.tradingview.com/v/UcdEQYkO/) example.

you cannot combine `hline` with `plot`. replace `hline` with `plot`

something like this:

```
fill(rsiUpperBand, p_rsi, title = 'Overbought Zone', color = rsi > 70 ? color.new(color.aqua, 0) : na)
```

Comment: its nor working, please give me exact code

Comment: The example that I gave you, works fine. [look](https://www.tradingview.com/x/PvkBp97k/)

Comment: Undeclared identifier 'p_rsi'

Answer (score 0):

To [fill](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_fill), the plot object [required argument](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_plot).

so, `plot(rsi,` ... requires an argument. in my example `p_rsi`

something like this:

```
p_rsi = plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
fill(rsiUpperBand, p_rsi, title = 'Overbought Zone', color = rsi > 55 ? color.new(color.aqua, 0) : na)
```